# Displaying month-wise date in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I have an ASP.NET GridView in which i want to show dates from selected month and year. Month and year fields are DropDownList and bound to XML data source. Is there any easy to do that or i have to use Code behind to add dates using iteration.

Comment: Do you have any code and XML already? If so, could you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to, although you (may) have to be careful with your XML. Take a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631365/populate-dropdownlist-from-xmldatasource), where Darin indicates that there was a bug in XmlDataSource which means you can only use attributes rather than node values -- and see if it helps.